# How to route to a different component when clicking a button inside an ion-popover in Ionic app?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-routing

In my Ionic app, I am using a Pop-up Controller to display an [ion-popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) below:

```
private showMechanicInfo(name: string) {
    this.popoverCtrl
      .create({
        component: MechanicPopoverComponent,
      })
      .then((alertEl) => {
        alertEl.present();
      });
  }
```

Within `popover.component.html`, I have the below button:

`<ion-button [routerLink]="['/mechanic-detail']">Profile</ion-button>`

When I click this button, I am not routed to the `mechanic-detail` component. If I place the same button on the `home` component though, it works as expected.

So for some reason, it isn't navigating when used in the pop-over.

Can someone please tell me what changes are required so that I can navigate from the pop-over to the `mechanic-detail` component?

Also, here are my routes:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'mechanic-detail',
    loadChildren: () => import('./mechanic-detail/mechanic-detail.module').then( m => m.MechanicDetailPageModule)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**popover.component.html**

```
<ion-button (click)="goMechDetail()">Profile</ion-button>
```

**popover.component.ts**

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { PopoverController } from "@ionic/angular";
```

...

```
  constructor(
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
```

...

```
  goMechDetail() {
    this.popoverController.dismiss().then(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(["mechanic-detail"], { replaceUrl: false });
      }, 100);
    });
  }
```